# How to insert & update the same inserted multiple record in SQL Server 2008 R2 using multithread in windows service(C#)?

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading

I've created class lib app. In which I'm creating multiple threads concurrently and each thread insert new record and update in same SQL server table. When I'm inserting record through threads some records are getting repeated & at the time of updating record thread is not getting appropriate value so I'm getting an exception from DAL is "Row not found/changed". What to do?
DAL : separate method for insert & update (LINQ to SQL)
Class Lib :

```
Class A
{
    Method AA()
    {
    Insert record code through DAL(Call  for DAL)
    //
    // some code here
    //
    Update the same record code through DAL(Call for DAL)
}

class B
{
    Method BB()
    {
        //Creating multiple threads simultaneously which calls the same method AA()
    }
}
}
```

But, in DAL method it gives an exception while updating or insert as I earlier mentioned.

Comment: This begs many questions: Are you using a transaction? What DAL are you using? How are you retrieving the new id when you insert a record?

Comment: I tried to resolve. I used transaction with isolation level read uncommitted. I was using .net class lib(as DAL). Retrieving new id from datacontext object after InsertOnSubmit(),SubmitChanges(). But, its working sometimes & sometimes not. So, what to do for this?

Comment: I got the solution on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did following things resolving my problem :
Select the table from .dbml file where you are inserting multiple records with multiple threads & right click on every field and in properties window set the property **Update Check** as **Never**. It's working as I wanted.[image].

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against running multiple threads to update one table:

1. You will run into problems with record/page/table locks and effectively your updates will run consecutively and not in parallel.
2. You will need to open multiple database connections (not good) or execute multiple queries on the same connection (what is the purpose of doing that on multiple threads then?).
3. It just doesn't seem to be necessary and overcomplicates something that SQL Server is prepared to do efficiently: insert multiple records for you.

Comment: I got the solution on this.